# Efficient use of as.numeric() and factor()

Tags: r, character, numeric

I have several hundred character vectors imported into R from a database - each has length of 6-7 million. They are either numeric or factor data that has character(letters) for labels - with levels to be set,all factor, all have some NAs. As an example

```
vecA <- c("1",NA, "2",....,NA, "100")
vecB <- c("smith", NA, NA, ... , "jones")
```

Is there an efficient way to coerce vecA to numeric and vecB to factor. The problem is I don't know where the numeric and factor vectors are in the data and it's tedious to go through them one by one.

Comment: are these vectors all in the same object, or are they individual objects? Do they have regular names, as in your example?

Comment: I'm going to call each vector, one at a time from a database, in a function. That function might be parallelized. There will be special characters in some of the strings - but only for the factor type data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably use `tryCatch()`, attempting first to convert each vector to class `"numeric"`. If `as.numeric()` throws a warning message (as it will when the input vector contains non-numeric characters), I'd catch the warning and instead convert the vector to class `"factor"`.

```
vecA <- c("1",NA, "2",NA, "100")
vecB <- c("smith", NA, NA, "jones")

myConverter <- function(X) tryCatch(as.numeric(X), 
                                    warning = function(w) as.factor(X))

myConverter(vecA)
# [1]   1  NA   2  NA 100
myConverter(vecB)
# [1] smith <NA>  <NA>  jones
# Levels: jones smith
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a regular expression? For each vector, match things that look like numbers.

```
convert.numeric <- function(vec) {
  if( grepl("^[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?$",vec)) == !is.na(vec)) ) {
    vec <- as.numeric(vec)
  } else { vec <- as.factor(vec) }
  return(vec)
}
```

Then wrap your vectors into a list and use `lapply`:

```
new.vectors <- lapply(old.vectors,convert.numeric)
```

Comment: Might be more efficient to test only the first 500 elements.